# ¿Por qué mi sumador me arroja basura? (lenguaje C)

Tags: c, funciones, matrices

En un ejercicio me dan una matriz completa de 3x3 y tengo que crear un menu con un switch con letras que haga lo siguiente:

Si se presiona 'a' sumar la diagonal principal de la matriz
Si se presiona 'b' sumar la diagonal secundaria de la matriz
Si se presiona 'c' sumar el triangulo superior considerando diagonal principal
Si se presiona 'd' sumar el triangulo inferior considerando diagonal principal
Si se presiona 'e' sumar el triangulo superior considerando diagonal secundaria
Si se presiona 'f' sumar el triangulo inferior considerando diagonal secundaria

Tiene que ser con esas letras y mediante funciones. Lo tengo hecho, pero el programa me devuelve basura cuando lo hago. Mi duda es si tengo algo mal escrito que cause que me devuelva basura y si lo tengo, que me dijeran en donde sería. Ya lo revisé como 5 veces y no lo puedo corregir. Gracias de antemano.

Les dejo el programa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define FIL 3
#define COL 3

int sumaDiagPrin (int m[][COL], int tam) ///LA FUNCION QUE SUMA LOS ELEMENTOS DE LA DIAGONAL PRINCIPAL.
{
    int i=0, res=0;

    for (i=0;i<tam-1;i++)
    {
        res= res + m[i][i];
    }

    return res;
}

int sumaDiagSecun (int m[][COL], int tam) ///LA FUNCION QUE SUMA LOS ELEMENTOS DE LA DIAGONAL SECUNDARIA.
{
    int i=0, res=0, j;

    j=i+2;

    for (i=0;i<tam-1;i++)
    {
        res= res + m[i][j];
        j--;
    }

    return res;
}

int sumaTrianSupDiagonalPrincipal (int m[][COL], int tam) ///SUMA LOS ELEMENTOS DEL TRIANGULO SUPERIOR DE LA DIAG PRINC.
{
    int i=0, j, res=0;

    j=i+1;

    for (i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        j=i+1;
        for(j=i+1;j<tam;j++)
        {
            res= res + m[i][j];
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int sumaTrianInfDiagonalPrincipal (int m[][COL], int tam) ///SUMA LOS ELEMENTOS DEL TRIANGULO INFERIOR DE LA DIAG PRIN.
{
    int j, i, res=0;

    for (i=1;i<tam;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<tam;j++)
        {
            if (i>j)
            {
                res= res + m[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}

int sumaTrianSupDiagonalSecundaria (int m[][COL], int tam) ///SUMA LOS ELEMENTOS DEL TRIANGULO INFERIOR DE LA DIAG SECUN.
{
    int i, j, res=0;

    for (i=0;i<tam-1;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<tam-1;j++)
        {
            res= res + m[i][j];
        }
    }

  return res;
}

int sumaTrianInfDiagonalSecundaria (int m[][COL], int tam) ///SUMA LOS ELEMENTOS DEL TRIANGULO INFERIOR DE LA DIAG SEC.
{
    int i, j, res=0, aux=0;

    for (j=tam-1;j>0;j--)
    {
        for (i=tam-1;i>aux;i--)
        {
            res = res + m[i][j];
        }

        aux++;
    }

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j, resultado=0;
    int mat[FIL][COL]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    char letra;

    printf("\nmenu de operaciones con matrices");
    printf("\nescriba 'a' para sumar la diagonal principal");
    printf("\nescriba 'b' para sumar la diagonal secundaria");
    printf("\nescriba 'c' para sumar el triangulo superior de la diagonal principal");
    printf("\nescriba 'd' para sumar el triangulo inferior de la diagonal principal");
    printf("\nescriba 'e' para sumar el triangulo superior de la diagonal secundaria");
    printf("\nescriba 'f' para sumar el triangulo inferior de la diagonal secundaria");
    scanf("%c", &letra);

    switch(letra)
    {
    case 'a':
        resultado=sumaDiagPrin(mat[FIL][COL], COL);
        printf("\nla suma de los elementos de la diagonal principal es %d", resultado);
        break;

    case 'b':
        resultado=sumaDiagSecun(mat[FIL][COL], COL);
        printf("\nla suma de los elementos de la diagonal secundaria es %d", resultado);
        break;

    case 'c':
        resultado=sumaTrianSupDiagonalPrincipal(mat[FIL][COL], COL);
        printf("\nla suma de los elementos del triangulo superior en la diagonal principal es %d", resultado);
        break;

    case 'd':
        resultado=sumaTrianInfDiagonalPrincipal(mat[FIL][COL], COL);
        printf("\nla suma de los elementos del triangulo inferior en la diagonal principal es %d", resultado);
        break;

    case 'e':
        resultado=sumaTrianSupDiagonalSecundaria(mat[FIL][COL], COL);
        printf("\nla suma de los elementos del triangulo superior en la diagonal secundaria es %d", resultado);
        break;

    case 'f':
        resultado=sumaTrianInfDiagonalSecundaria(mat[FIL][COL], COL);
        printf("\nla suma de los elementos del triangulo inferior en la diagonal secundaria es %d", resultado);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: y exactamente que basura te arroja?

Comment: En vez de sumar los valores de la matriz me tira cosas como 693615, 687216, -735 y mas numeros raros. La matriz y las variables estan inicializadas y es muy raro que lo haga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ¿Que son los arrays en c?

Tanto las matrices como los arays en C son direcciones de memoria que apuntan a un espacio determinado en tiempo de compilación.

Cuando  declaras un array de esta forma

`mat[FIL][COL]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};`

Lo que estas haciendo  es declarando una dirección para `mat`y un bloque de memoria para almacenar los 9 enteros que ya les adjuntaste.

Entonces cuando dices por ejemplo `mat[0][0]` el se va a la primera dirección y toma el valor que hay allí.

### Y ¿Cuál es el problema?

El problema esta en todos y cada uno de las llamadas a las funciones que haces

`resultado=sumaDiagPrin(mat[FIL][COL], COL);`

Al estar FIL y Col definidos como 3 y 3 respectivamente, en vez de enviar la dirección del inicio de la matriz que era lo que se esperaba, estas enviando una posición de la matriz, que en realidad esta fuera de la matriz ( la matriz va de 0,0 hasta 2,2), por lo que te arroja basura.

Cuando compilé tu codigo me arrojo estos *warnings* 122 32

*[Warning] passing argument 1 of 'sumaDiagPrin' makes pointer from integer without a cast*

_ [Note] expected 'int (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'int'_

la funcion necesita un puntero a la primera direccion de la matriz y tu le estas enviando un entero. Esto puede funcionar en algunos extraños casos, por eso me dice que es un peligro pero no necesariamente un error.. en tu caso si es un error.

### La solución

Haz la llamada a la función correctamente. solamente dando el nombre de la matriz. Así:

`resultado=sumaDiagPrin(mat, COL);`
para todas y cada una de las llamadas a las funciones y voila!